# Checking/getting JAVA_HOME Variable from Java

Tags: java, java-home

Inside a Java program, how can I read the `JAVA_HOME` variable (to be sure it is set the correct way)? 
Similarly, how can I get  the path of the `bin` folder? That is, the path usually set in Windows via:

`path %path%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Note: I am using the OpenJDK build by [Alexkasko](https://github.com/alexkasko).

Comment: *"how can I read"*  What feature are you trying to implement by knowing that?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I am using a portable R distribution and I need a portable Java as well (in order to use some R-Java Interfaces). I copy the OpenJDK files in the portabla R folder then I need to set the path to them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since both PATH and JAVA_HOME are environment variables, you should be able to read both of their values in a similar way:

```java
String javaHome = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
String path = System.getenv("PATH");
```

Answer (score 23):

Try

```
String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
```

Comment: I get:

``String javaHome = System.getProperties("java.home");``  
``^``
``required: no arguments``
``found: String``
``reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length ``
``1 error``

Comment: Sorry, it's getProperty, not getProperties.

Comment: Thanks, System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") didn't work for me as the variable was not exported (non-environment variable)

Comment: Java properties and environment variables are two different things, and from the question it looks like he specifically asked for the latter.

Answer (score 4):

Use [System.getenv()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29) to read the value.

```
 System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");`

Answer (score 0):

On windows you could execute the `set` command from you application as you would do in your cmd and afterwards handle the output:

```
Process p;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("set JAVA_HOME");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

But as answered by the others

```
System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
```

would be the nicer way.

However if anyone needs an alternative, see above. :D