# how to get java home in Linux?

Tags: linux

Inside a Java program, how can I read the JAVA_HOME variable (to be sure it is set the correct way)? Similarly, how can I get the path of the bin folder? That is, the path usually set in Windows via:

path %path%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_HOME and PATH are environment variables. So you can get values like this :

```
String javaHome = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
String path = System.getenv("PATH");
```

Please follow below link for this :

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297326/checking-getting-java-home-variable-from-java`